# Algorithm for comparing two lists

Tags: java, algorithm, list, data-structures

I have a list of objects that I am displaying on the screen.  The user can change them as they like, and then hit submit.  In the submit method I am taking the original list, which I stored, and the current list, and comparing them.  I have to create a third list that contains all the objects that were added, removed, or changed with an action code to specify which it was.  The objects have an id to identify them, which defaults to 0.

How can I do this?  This is the best I could come up with (pseudocode) but it seems sloppy.

```
for (currentObject : objects in current list)
    if (currentObject.id is 0)
        //Was added
    for (oldObject : objects in original list)
        if (currentObject.id == oldObject.id)
            //Existed - compare other fields to see if changed

for (oldObject1 : objects in original list)
    boolean existed = false;
    for (currentObject1 : objects in current list)
        if(oldObject1.id == currentObject1.id)
            existed=true;
    if (!existed)
        //Was removed
```

Comment: Is the object ID unique?

Comment: If your object ids are unique, you can get a lot of mileage out of sorting the original and the current list before comparing them.

Comment: @DavidH object id is unique coming from the database.  But all objects added on UI will have id of 0.

Answer (score 6):

If ordering doesn't matter and all you care about is whether the elements were added or removed, you might want to consider changing your data structures and using `Set` rather than `List`.  The `Set` type is specifically designed to determine whether or not elements exist and to do so efficiently, at the cost that you no longer remember the order of the elements.

For example, using `HashSet`, you could do the following:

```
Set<T> oldElems = new HashSet<T>(originalList);
Set<T> newElems = new HashSet<T>(currentList);

for (T obj : oldElems) {
    if (!newElems.contains(obj)) {
        /* ... this object was removed ... */
    }
}

for (T obj : newElems) {
    if (!oldElems.contains(obj)) {
        /* ... this object was added ... */
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, if I remember correctly Java has a method for identifying elements common to two Collections.

Comment: @Daniel- There's operations like `retainAll` and `removeAll`, but they destructively modify the original containers.  Though maybe that's what the OP wants?

Comment: For a type to be used in a `HashSet`, you need to make sure that `equals()` and `hashCode()` are properly implemented. And I see that you're only handling adding and removing, what about the modified case ?

Comment: @CostiCiudatu- You can think of a modification as an add followed by a remove (or vice-versa).  Would that not work here?

Comment: @Daniel I tried using retain all and remove all but it didn't work.  For example if I take the oldList and removeAll(newList) to get all the removed elements, it counts modifications as a removal, which it is not.

Comment: @templatetypedef I will have to think further on this.  There does need to be a concrete distinction between a modification and an add/remove.  I think in this solution a modification will show up as both an add and a remove.  Maybe if I took your solution and made two new sets (added and removed) and then compared the common elements to get modifications?  I'll play with it.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but iterating through both sets at the same time would take O(n), while your implementation would take O(n log n).

Comment: @Dukeling- All operations on a `HashSet` take expected amortized O(1) time, so this should still take O(n) time rather than O(n log n) time.  If we used a `TreeSet` here, then yes, it would take O(n log n) time.

Comment: Oh right, `HashSet`, I really should stop only reading half of answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with one loop, by continuously maintaining the 3-way result list. If you can override `equals()` to depend on `id`s, that's fine. If not, check the code under *update*.

Here's the code, see the explanation below:

```
List<T> origList = ...;
List<T> newList = ...;

List<T> addedList = new ArrayList<T>();
List<T> deletedList = new ArrayList<T>();
List<T> changedList = new ArrayList<T>();

deletedList.addAll(origList);

for(T t : newList) {
    int origIndex = deletedList.indexOf(t);
    if (origIndex < 0) {
        addedList.add(t);
    } else {
        T origT = deletedList.remove(origIndex);
        if(t.compareTo(origT) != 0) {
            changedList.add(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I presumed that `equals()` will check the `id`, and `compareTo()` will check all other fields.

**Explanation:**

You remove all elements from `deletedList` that were also present in `newList`, so the result is the *deleted* items.

You add all new elements to the `addedList` that were not present in the original list.

If both are present and the objects *differ*, they'll go to the `changedList`.

If both are present and the objects *are the same* then we don't add it anywhere.

**Notes:**

If new objects have an ID of `0`, they will not be present in `origList` (since we suppose they have been already created).

When I last time implemented this, I created a *separate method* to compare the objects field-by-field, so I could separate the comparison logic from standard Java methods (actually it was also declared on an `interface`)

I created this with `List`s, but actually you can use it with any type of `Collection`. Using with List will preserve the original order.

**Update:**

Try overriding your `equals` this way (I skipped the typecheck and the casting):

```
public boolean equals(T other) {
    if (this.id == 0) {
        return this == other;
    }
    return this.id == other.id;
}
```

The not-yet-created instances are equal to themselves only. The already-created ones are checked by id.

Comment: The issue I ran into with overriding equals to just check id is that on the UI, when they click remove, my action listener is calling list.remove(Object o).  By overriding equals like this it caused a bug because all newly added items in the list on the UI will have id=0.  So when I remove it is just removing the first object it finds with id=0 and not necessarily the one they selected to remove.  This is a JSF app by the way.

Comment: If you cannot use the `equals()`, then you can replace the `remove()` with an `Iterator` loop. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Sounds good i'll take a look.  Looking at your code I think you meant addedList.add(t) instead of newList.add(t) right?  That part was throwing me off a bit.

Comment: @bhouse Yeah, my mistake. Now corrected and added the code for the `remove()`.

Comment: The equals override you provided is good, that will work-around my other issue.  Back to your original suggestion then, the line
    T origT = deletedList.remove(t)
This is a syntax error since remove(Obj) returns a boolean.  Based on what it looks like you are trying to do I think I can take the boolean, change the next if to
    if(!booleanReturnedAbove)
but then I am confused on how the next line will work.

Comment: @bhouse You were right, I updated the code (I was coding it by heart). Now it should be better. Also deleted the code for the `remove()` replacement, but actually that may be a more effective solution than this one.